# Why doesn't 'ls -a' command line tool show the '/etc' directory

Tags: unix, ls

noob command line user here...

I'm trying to setup a postGIS database and the interwebs told me that I need to go into the `/etc` dir of my server. This directory does exist and I have been into it, but the `ls -a` command doesn't list `/etc` as one of its directories.

Why doesn't it show `/etc`?
As an added bonus - are there any other special cases not listed with `ls -a`?

Comment: If your current directory is `/etc`, the only name for it that is visible to `ls -a` is `.`, the current directory (unless you specify `ls -a /etc`, for example).  Experiment with: `cd /; ls -lid etc /etc; cd /etc; ls -lid .`.  And it helps to show more precisely the commands you are executing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you mean `/etc` at the root of your filesystem, which is not strictly related to your server. You can see it with `ls -a /`.

If you're currently in a directory and you're convinced that `etc` is there but just not showing up in `ls`, you can prove it by trying to enter it with `cd etc` (no slash). I'm fairly certain it won't work.

Comment: Yep, I assumed that I was automatically put into the root filesystem when logged into the root user, I guess that's not the case

Comment: You can tell where you are with the `pwd` (print working directory) command.

Answer (score 0):

I just think that you have something messed up in your mind. the directory is called etc not /etc, you use this " / " when you are using for example cd in order to specify that this is a directory that you want to go to. so if you would actually go on your terminal and add:

```
cd /
ls -a
```

you will see that after a-b-c-d- there will be the etc directory without the / in the name.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone who has used unix/linux knows that when a person makes reference to /etc, they are making reference to the directory "etc", located in the root directory ("/").  Let's not make this a difficult place for people who are seeking answers to questions.  If you don't know the answer, the simply remain silent.

That said, asking the question again, regardless of which directory are current at, if you enter "ls -la /etc" at the command prompt, you should receive a listing of files in etc.  It works that way in unix as well as in linux.  However, in OSX it simply returns /etc/ -> private/etc.

You should be able to list the contents of a directory, even if it is a symbolic link.  Why do I have to enter "ls -la /private/etc"?  What is the purpose of using a symbolic link if you have use the actual directory path?